# Queries prefixed with wildcards are not supported in Azure DevOps code search

Tags: azure-devops, filtering

So how do I search for terms starting with anything and have specific letters/word in the middle/end?

Say i want to search for *XYZ*

Is pattern matching the only option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wildcards cannot be used as a prefix in a simple search string. However, you *can* use prefix wildcards with the other search filter functions.

Source: [How To: Use Code Search - Broaden your search by using wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/advanced-code-search-syntax?view=vsts#broaden-your-search-by-using--wildcards)

> You can use wildcard characters anywhere in your search string except as a prefix in a simple search string or a query that uses a code type filter. For example, you cannot use a search query such as *RequestHandler or class:?RequestHandler. However, you can use prefix wildcards with the other search filter functions; for example, the search query strings file:*RequestHandler.cs and repo:?Handlers are valid.